# Take rapid fire or continous pictures using phonegap camera api

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I came across several answers for using camera api in phone gap. However, I cannot find the one that will help to take a continuous picture or rapid fire pictures using phone gap camera api. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sabarish, The standard camera API does NOT allow this. There is a suggestion that multiple images can be capture with the Capture API. However, it says:

> Starts an asynchronous operation to capture images using the device's
>   camera application. The operation allows users to capture more than
>   one image in a single session.

There is NO suggestion of having any control over how and when the images are taken. You will likely want to try [one of the plugins](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/plugins/list_of_plugins.html). --Jesse